# Using C code in ROS, including a .c file in ROS

Tags: rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a .c file (and a corresponding .h file) that has a function I would like to call inside my ROS package.

I altered the cmakelist.txt to include the .c file
rosbuild_add_executable(myNodeName src/mainFile.cpp src/cFile.c)

This does not build however if I change the file's extension to cpp and then change the corresponding rosbuild statement it builds fine.

I looked at "how-to-develop-interface-from-c-program-with-ros" and "shell-script-and-c-program-in-ros" on this site.

Is my only option to build a wrapper for the .c file ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65424/using-c-code-in-ros,-including-a-.c-file-in-ros/) by [canatan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3563/canatan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [canatan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3563/canatan/) on 2013-06-18**:
All I had to do was add the c99 flags to the cmakelist file to make it work.
add_definitions(-std=c99)

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-06-19**:
Canatan, you should include that response as an answer.

**Comment by [canatan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3563/canatan/) on 2013-06-24**:
done thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All I had to do was add the c99 flags to the cmakelist file to make it work. add_definitions(-std=c99)

---

Originally posted by [canatan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3563/canatan/) with karma: 41 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0